# HTTPS SEO and Canonical

Tags: .htaccess, https, seo, canonical-link

As i have now https version of my website is it seo friendly to have "permanently moved" status 301, 200 and redirect the http url to https ?

I am using .htaccess to do this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here is the example of the non http url test:
Go to https://httpstatus.io/ and test url http://sunnybeachtaxi.com/from-Sunny-Beach-to-Burgas-airport-options-Burgas-1-4-35/book/

returns 301, 200

Now another question is what canonical url should i use http or https ? I know google prefers https but still not sure. At the moment http urls are indexed and https are not becouse they appear to google as dublicates.

What is the best steps to achive this ? Should i first remove the http urls and then submit to google index the https ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS then you should first of all purchase SSL certificate and activate it for your site. Nowadays google does not allow some site which is running without HTTPS. Just add SSL to your site and you do not need to submit it again into google webmaster just because of that if you have update time to time sitemap of your website. crawler automatically understand.

What is canonical URL's?
A canonical tag is a different way of telling search engines that a specific URL represents the master copy of a page. visit this SEO MOZ page for more information. https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, i have SSL certificate and the website is running well on https already. It was just all the urls in google index are http and i want everything replace with https without affecting seo.

At the moment i updated the sitemap with all the urls set to https and submitted to google index. Also i am redirecting all non http adresses with 301 code to their https equivaletnt. now i will wait of course to see...

just wanted to ask some of you who are seo experts if this is the best way of transitioning to https on server site, urls, google index

Comment: Okay, so as per you told you've done all those activities and your site is running into HTTPS. so don't worry dear google convert automatically your all URL's into HTTPS. as per my experience in SEO and digital marketing fields, you guys are going the right way. still, if you have any query related to this post your question or contact me. Happy to Help!